# win 8 RP to win 8 rtm

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I was developing winRT app using Win8 RP and visual studio express 2012. The Win 8 RTM is available and just by installing the Win 8 sdk can I test winRT app on my win 8 RP or do I need to upgrade my OS to RTM.
I mean what is the difference from developer point of view are there new API available or any new features in RTM sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RTM tools (SDK, Visual Studio, etc.) require RTM version of Windows 8.

Comment: Are there any API changes in WinRT sdk for RTM version?

Comment: That is correct. If you have an MSDN subscription the RTM is available for download now. The upgrade from RP is pretty painless, I've done it with several machines already.

Comment: I don't have a list of actual changes in front of me but yes, there were changes to the APIs.